# Convert struct values to row in big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to convert values of struct to independent row

My table looks like

```
|id | details
| 1 | {d_0:{id:'1_0'},d_1:{id:'1_1'}}
| 2 | {d_0:{id:'2_0'},d_1:{id:'2_1'}}
```

```
Expected Result (will be flattening the inner struct here)
| id  |
|'1_0'|
|'1_1'|
|'2_0'|
|'2_1'|
```

Since IDK how many fields will be there in `details` is there any way to convert all the individual fields of the struct as independent rows.

The schema for all values in the `details.d_0`, `details.d_1`,... will be the same.

Any help or pointer to resources is appreciated.

Comment: Are the values under `details` column STRUCT or JSON?

Comment: They are struct

Answer (score 1):

You may use this query that iterates array to achieve your desired output:

Creating table:

```
CREATE TABLE `<proj_id>.<dataset>.<table>` as 
WITH data AS (
 SELECT "1" AS id, STRUCT(STRUCT( '1_0' as id) as d_0, STRUCT( '1_1' as id) as d_1) as details,
 union all SELECT "2" AS id, STRUCT(STRUCT( '2_0' as id) as d_0, STRUCT( '2_1' as id) as d_1) as details
),

tier_1 as (
select id,details.*  from data 
)

select * from tier_1
```

Actual Query:

```
DECLARE i INT64 DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE query_ary ARRAY<STRING> DEFAULT 

  ARRAY(
select concat(column_name,'.id')  from  `<dataset>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`
    WHERE
      table_name = <your-table> AND regexp_contains(column_name, r'd\_\d')
  );
CREATE TEMP TABLE result(id STRING);
LOOP
  SET i = i + 1;
  IF i > ARRAY_LENGTH(query_ary) THEN 
    LEAVE; 
  END IF;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '''
   INSERT result
   SELECT ''' || query_ary[ORDINAL(i)] || ''' FROM `<proj_id>.<dataset>.<table>`
  ''';

END LOOP; 

SELECT * FROM result;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Anjela B, I went with this solution yesterday. It works well, but the creation of this table takes a long time in my case. I will check for some other solutions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select id from your_table,
unnest(split(translate(format('%t', details), '()', ''), ', ')) id
```

if applied to sample data in your question as

```
with your_table as (
 select "1" id, struct(struct('1_0' as id) as d_0, struct('1_1' as id) as d_1) details union all 
 select "2", struct(struct('2_0'), struct('2_1')) 
)
```

output is

[image]

Comment: This looks good @Mikhail Berlyant, I'll give it a try.